# System can not reboot after completing installation of Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04, shutdown

After installation on a dual boot finished, I was prompted to "Please remove the installation medium and press Enter". After I did that, I get the following errors and computer won't restart:

[image]

I had to force shut down with long press of power button. When I startup, I can boot Ubuntu but it cannot shut down or restart.
I have tried `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"` and `apm=power_off` but still cannot shut down.

Comment: please, let me know if any more info would be helpful.

Comment: Last log from shut down logging is `Journal stopped`